# How to find encapsulating function name from line number

Tags: linux, awk

I am looking at a log file which just tells me the filename and the line number inside that file that has the Error. What I am interested is knowing the encapsulating function. For example, here are the contents of the log file

```
    Error: foo.file on line wxy
    Error: foo.file on line xyz
    .
    .
    .
```

and here are the contents of the file foo.file

```
function abc_1234 (...)
    .
    .
    .


    endfunction

    function def_442 ()
    .
    .
    .
   //Following line number is  WXY
    assign Z ==== X;

    endfunction


    function ghi(...)
    .
    .
    .


  //Following line number is  XYZ
    assign X = X;
    endfunction

   .
   .
   .
```

Based on the above log file, I want to get function names  `def_442` and `ghi` returned. I have tried the following

```
# look for function definitions and record the function name
# in the func_name variable
/function [[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*[[:blank:]]*([^)]*)/ {
  func_name = substr($2, 1, index($2, "(")-1);
}

# when we reach the target line number, print out the current
# value of func_name
NR == target {
  print func_name
}
```

but It is failing on `abc_1234 (...)` and `def_442 (...)` as there is a space before `(`

Comment: am I correct in assuming that you are searching through [Octave source code](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.3/Defining-Functions.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of parsing the source code properly, so that we're not thrown off by comments or strings that might falsely match, the below script simply searches backwards from the given line numbers in the given files for the string `"function "` (in quotes so that you can see the invisible trailing space):

```
#!/bin/sh
while read -r error file on line linenum
do
  : "SC2034: $error, $on, and $line are unused"
  printf 'For error in %s on line %d:\n' "$file" "$linenum"
  ed -s "$file" << EOF | sed '1d; s/function //; s/(.*//'
  $linenum
  ?function 
  q
EOF
  echo
done < logfile
```

The outer `while` loop reads the `logfile` into two important variables: "$file" and "$linenum". It then invokes `ed` on "$file" and gives it a here-document with a list of instructions, namely:

1. go to line "$linenum"
2. search backwards for the string `"function "` -- there's that invisible space
3. `q`uit

The output of `ed` will be two lines: the contents of $linenum, followed by the line before it that matches `"function "`. That's why we pass all of that output through `sed`, which is given three commands:

- `1d` -- delete the first line of the output
- `s/function //` -- delete the string `"function "`
- `s/(.*//` -- delete from the opening parenthesis onwards

Sample output, given your input, is:

```
For error in foo.file on line 13:
    def_442

For error in foo.file on line 25:
    ghi
```

Reformat to taste.